# Call method when Button leaves Highlighted State

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I want to perform a action when a button is highlighted and perform another action when it leaves the highlighted state. Any advice?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use KVO

```
[button addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"highlighted" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:NULL];
```

Then

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([@"highlighted" isEqualToString:keyPath]) {

        NSNumber *new = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
        NSNumber *old = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey];

        if (old && [new isEqualToNumber:old]) {
            NSLog(@"Highlight state has not changed");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Highlight state has changed to %d", [object isHighlighted]);
        }
    }
}
```

You only really care about the changes and this will be called every time the state changes e.g. if you move select and then with your finger still down drag outside of the button

Comment: NSKeyValueChangeNewKey, NSKeyValueChangeOldKey

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
self.testButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[self.testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(methodOne) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(methodTwo) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: No this doesn't work because the Button leaves the highlighted state before it performs the TouchUpInside action (at least thats what i guessed after testing...)

Comment: It's not as clean as that as you can do things like drag out of the button causing the button to lose it's highlight

Comment: To account for the edge cases with dragging outside, you could change the last line to: [self.testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(t2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside|UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];

Comment: @AzzUrr1 are you sure it leaves the highlighted state before performing the action?

Comment: @PaulHunter changing `UIControlEventTouchUpInside|UIControlEventTouchUpOutside` does not catch the button becoming un-highlighted when dragged outside

Comment: I'm not really sure but I made some tests with the different states and events and my assumption was that the button leaves the highlighted state before the TouchUp actions were called