# button highlight state and gestures

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I've been struggling with this for a while already and some
help would be useful.

Imagine I have a `UIButton`, which starts in `highlighted`/`selected` state.
If a user taps it, then `highlighted`/`selected` state changes.

I've implemented this and it works fine. Problems start
for example if user taps inside the button region,
does not release her/his finger, and moves mouse
outside the button area -- at this time my Button
would usually lose `highlighted`/`selected` state.
Anyway, I have solved this issue too, by overriding `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside`
and making button keep the state it had before...

But now another problem comes in, similar to the above,
if a user taps the button, does not release his/her
finger, and moves the finger to the right say (horizontally,
which also makes my dialog for instance go to the right),
then I again lose "selected/highlighted" state....

I believe again some kind of gesture similar to - but different -
than `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside` is being called which
removes my selected state...

Do you know what can be going in here? Any advice appreciated.

ps. I have fixed all the issues by just setting different images
for normal/selected states using the interface builder.

Comment: This might be useful for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968401/call-method-when-button-leaves-highlighted-state?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

For the highlighted effect you can use the: `setHighlighted` of `UIButton` class.

When you start touching the button set the highlighted property of button to YES.

when you start touch:

```
yourButton.highlighted = YES;
```

When you stop touch:

```
yourButton.highlighted = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed all the issues by just setting different images for normal/selected states using the interface builder.